# Parse URL From Right - Jquery/Regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a URL that is very similar to:

```
url/Search/SearchResult?SearchText=FirstName%20Lastname
```

Using JQ, how can I parse Everything after the `"SearchText="` , while replacing `%20` with a space.

I'm looking to return a string in the following format:

```
"FirstName LastName"
```

I figure this can be done easily with RegEx, but I struggle working with it, so examples would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: `decodeURIComponent(string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
var value = decodeURIComponent(url.split('?')[1].split('=')[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.*=|%20
```

Try this.Replace by .See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/84

Comment: This will add a space at the begining.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte that is a smaller problem and can be tackled easily

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var searchText = document.URL.split("SearchText=")[1].split("%20");
var name = searchText[0] + " " + searchText[1];
```

Comment: That's only work if the SearchText was definitely the last parameter, and if there were no escaped characters in the string: you'd need to `uriDecodeComponent` the strings afterwards. But there are more complete solutions on a few other questions here.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include an explanation of your code? It helps the reader more than you might think.